# How to make nbviewer display local files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've got nbviewer installed and working. I see it has a `--localfiles` option that takes a folder name. It says: "Serving local notebooks in /home/gb/S14/inclass, this can be a security risk"

But I can't figure out the URL format to get it to look for the file there. The code adds a handler for `/localfile/(.*)` but that doesn't seem to get triggered.

Anyone know how to format name to give to trigger loading a local file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One minute later and it occurs to me that the front page might not support even though the server does. Sure enough, `http://localhost:5000/localfile/PythonReference.ipynb?create=1` renders the local notebook.

Comment: Suppose that i have a file /home/<name>/foo.ipynb, http://localhost:5000/localfile/home/<name>/foo.ipynb is not working for me, so what url should I use to view the ipynb file?

Comment: It only serves files below where it is running, maybe even only in the same directory. So, run nbiewer in your home directory, then ask for localhost:5000/localfile/foo.ipynb?create=1

Comment: This is still not working for me, but I manage to use localhost:5000/url/localhost/home/<name>/foo.ipynb to make it work. Thanks for you answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to http://localhost:5000/localfile will display a directory browser, starting at the path you passed to `--localfiles`; you can then just click on a `.ipynb` file.

Comment: I can't able to access the file tree, I am using this command.
```` docker run -p 8080:8080 jupyter/nbviewer python3 -m nbviewer --localfiles=home/muneeb/homiwoo/src/applications/machine-learning/oshi_projects/comparison --port=8080 ````
But still getting 404 not found when trying to access it. http://localhost:8080/localfiles