# nbviewer - fails to server localfiles

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020129/how-to-make-nbviewer-display-local-files): I am trying to serve local files on a local nbviewer server.

I have an installation of nbviewer in `/home/user/nbviewer/nbviewer/` on a remote server where I start nbviewer in `/home/user/` with

```
[servername]$ python -m nbviewer --debug --no-cache --no-check-certificate --localfiles=/home/user/path/to/notebooks/
```

This shows the following nbviewer output on the remote server

```
[I 181122 16:39:17 app:124] Not indexing notebooks
[I 181122 16:39:17 app:128] Not using cache
[I 181122 16:39:17 app:212] Not validating SSL certificates
[W 181122 16:39:17 app:263] Serving local notebooks in /home/user/path/to/notebooks/, this can be a security risk
```

Now I try to serve a notebook `/home/user/path/to/notebooks/test.ipynb`, so in the browser on my local machine I enter the url

```
http://servername:5000/localfile/test.ipynb
```

This gives a 404 error

```
[W 181122 16:51:40 log:53] 404 GET /localfile/test.ipynb
```

As suggested in the linked answer I also tried to access

```
http://servername:5000/localfile/
```

to see a list of files that are served but I get again a 404 error.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging `nbviewer/nbviewer/providers/local/handlers.py` I saw that nbviewer sends a 404 error if it does not have read access to the file. Should be a 401 Unauthorized error in my opinion but anyways, after changing permission on the file I wanted to host, it worked