# Is there an HTML tag to display .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My goal is to present `.ipynb` file to the management. However, some management is non-IT. So, I would like to present them like [GitHub](https://github.com/kidfrom/hacktiv8-ftds-fase0/blob/master/day02/pandas/main.ipynb)

or is there a `.js` library to do this?

Comment: If you want to explore options other than PDF, you can use nbviewer perhaps? Your example using that is [here](https://github.com/kidfrom/hacktiv8-ftds-fase0/blob/master/day02/pandas/main.ipynb). [It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020129/how-to-make-nbviewer-display-local-files) you can install nbviewer locally via the github repo. Also, see the first three paragraphs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094775/8508004) and [discussion here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-do-you-share-notebooks-best-practices-around-sharing-to-external-stakeholders/3617/8).

Comment: And since you specifically mention a `.js` library, I'll highlight that [nbpreview](https://github.com/jsvine/nbpreview) that is featured in one of the links above, is built on [notebookjs](https://github.com/jsvine/notebookjs).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your .ipynb file to a PDF file

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to pdf notebook.ipynb
```

Then use django to render as a pdf file

```
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404

def pdf_view(request):
    try:
        return FileResponse(open('notebook.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise Http404()
```